# How To Properly Save To The Pictures Folder

Tags: android, image, bitmap, save, mediastore

I am trying to save a bitmap that is created by the user to the default 'Pictures' folder on the device. I will start with the option that seems to be the more common method:

```
public void saveImageToExternalStorage(String filename, Bitmap image) {
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator;
    try {
        File directory = new File(path);
        if (!directory.exists()) {
            directory.mkdirs();
        }

        File file = new File(directory, filename + ".jpeg");
        file.createNewFile();

        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outputStream);

        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is supposed to save to the 'Pictures' folder, but `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()` seems to create a new file structure like this `file://storage/emulated/11/Pictures/` and save the picture to that. I have also tried `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)` with the same result. But this is not the default 'Pictures' folder on any of my test devices or emulators. Which led me to look for other methods, and I found this:

```
public void saveImageToExternalStorage(String filename, Bitmap image) {
    try {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, filename);
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, System.currentTimeMillis());
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");

        Uri filepath = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
        OutputStream outputStream = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(filepath);

        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outputStream);
        outputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This actually saves to the default file structure, which apparently looks like this: `content://media/external/images/media/4282`. But there seems to be no way to specify the filename of the image (`Media.TITLE` just sets the title attribute, not the actual filename), it saves as a (seemingly) random string of numbers. I looked at the [API Guide](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.Media.html) for `MediaStore.Images.Media` and there does not seem to be any other variable that would set the filename. This also does not seem to be the correct way of saving, according to the [Android Developer Guides](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html). I would like to know if there is any way of saving to this folder, while also setting my own filename. And if this method could produce unforeseen problems on other devices.

**EDIT:**
For anyone interested this is my current code, based on the answer by @CommonsWare:

```
public void saveImageToExternalStorage(Context context, String filename, Bitmap image) throws IOException {
    File directory = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File file = new File(directory, filename + ".jpeg");

    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
    mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outputStream);

    outputStream.flush();
    outputStream.getFD().sync();
    outputStream.close();

    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context, new String[] {file.getAbsolutePath()}, null, null);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> This is supposed to save to the 'Pictures' folder

`getExternalStorageDirectory()` returns the root of external storage, not some location inside of it (e.g., `Pictures/`, `DCIM/`, `Movies/`).

> I have also tried Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) with the same result

That will give you the proper directory, or whatever the device thinks the proper directory is (usually named `Pictures/` in external storage for whoever the current user is).

> but Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() seems to create a new file structure like this file://storage/emulated/11/Pictures/

The `11` is a bit unusual, and `getAbsolutePath()` does not return something with a `file://` scheme, but otherwise that seems about right.

> But this is not the default 'Pictures' folder on any of my test devices or emulators.

I do not know how you have determined this.

> I would like to know if there is any way of saving to this folder, while also setting my own filename.

Start with your first sample, switching to `DIRECTORY_PICTURES`. Then:

- have `outputStream` be a `FileOutputStream`
- call `outputStream.getFD().sync()` after `flush()` and before `close()`
- use `MediaScannerConnection` and its `scanFile()` method to arrange for the `MediaStore` to index the image, so it is available to on-device galleries, desktop OS file managers, etc.

Comment: When I create the file with `File file = new File(directory, fileName + ".jpeg")` I log `file.toString()` and it gives me `/storage/emulated/11/Pictures/<filename>.jpeg`. But when I open Android File Transfer, the location is actually `file://storage/emulate/11/Pictures/`. While the 'Pictures' folder I want to save to is in the users directory, along with the 'file://' folder. I made your adjustments, but I still have the same results. The only thing I didn't add was `MediaScannerConnection.scanFile()`, do you have any examples of that?

Comment: @Bryan: "But when I open Android File Transfer" -- I do not know what this is, sorry. "do you have any examples of that" -- `MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context, new String[] { file.getAbsolutePath() }, null, null);`

Comment: Wow, that fixed it! I guess Android makes a temporary location for `/storage/emulated/...` and when you call `MediaScannerConnection.scanFile()` it pulls everything from that location. After I made that call, everything I had taken from last week showed up in the Pictures folder. As for Android File Transfer, it's an application to transfer files between your [android devices and a Mac](https://www.android.com/filetransfer/). Windows uses the standard Explorer file transfer window.

Comment: How about Android Q?

Comment: @KalyaganovAlexey: You will wind up using `insert()` in `MediaStore` to add the entry and get a `Uri` that you can use to write out the bytes of the picture.

Answer (score 0):

With Android 6.0 Marshmallow (API >= 23), Google introduced a new permission model.

You have to request permission at run-time:

```
String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
requestPermissions(permissions, WRITE_REQUEST_CODE);
```

and handle the result in onRequestPermissionsResult(),

```
File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
    Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
File file = new File(path, "db.JPG");
try {
    file.createNewFile();
}
catch (IOException e) {
    Toast.makeText(this.getApplicationContext(),
    "createNewFile:"+e.toString(),
    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

then

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
    sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,
    Uri.parse("file://" + filename)));
}
else {
    sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE,
    Uri.parse("file://" + filename)));
}
```

to show in the gallery.